# How cast DbContext to MyContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have an Interface with property DbContext Db. Then, I have a class which implements this Interface. In that class, I want to assign MyContext to property Db. This works, but I can't cast Db to MyContext. How should I properly make this cast?

```
public interface ILine
{
    DbContext Db { get; }
}
public class Line: ILine
{
    public DbContext Db { get; private set; }

    public int SomeMethod()
    {
        using(Db = new MyContext()){
        //var temp = (MyContext)Db.rall.where(p=>p.id = 1).count();
        // Line above cant be compiled, .rall is underlined, is specific for MyContext
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `DbContext`. That's the base class of *all* contexts. Use the type you really want. If you want to abstract the context, you can create an interface or base class that will be implemented by the contexts you want to inject. After all, you can't expect `ILine` to work with a CustomersContext. It has to be something that provides the data you need

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have more Lines which implements ILine, each line use own context.

Comment: That works just fine with interfaces. Or you can make the interface generic with a type constraint that requires a specific interface or base type. In any case, there's no reason to use `DbContext` and you just found out why you *shouldn't* use it

Comment: Besides, putting the DbContext in the *interface* means it will be available to the class's clients. Those clients won't be able to work without using type casts themselves. What's the point then? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Casting has a lower precedence than the dot operator. Try

`((MyContext)Db).rall`

Comment: @Kali26 no it doesn't. That just covers up the problem - using `DbContext` in the first place. Use the correct type, or use interfaces if you want to use different contexts. Casting like this *breaks* type checking for no benefit

Comment: @Kali26 Thanks, would you accept the answer please?

Comment: Note that this will cause a NullReferenceException if the DbContext passed is not actually a MyContext. You should either keep type security like @PanagiotisKanavos suggested, or use the is-Pattern like if(Db is MyContext context) context.rall

Answer (score 1):

if your context have not Covariance and contravariance problem
http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/
you can use like this

```
    (Db  as MyContext).rall.where(p=>p.id = 1).count();
```